# Projected coordinate system for South America

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, south-america

Does anybody have any suggestions for a projected coordinate system for the Northern part of South America?  I have a data set that reaches from Venezuela to Southern Peru and I'd like to do some spatial autocorrelation on it.  However, the current WGS84 is obviously a geographic coordinate system and not suitable for this type of analysis.  I could just stick it in UTM 19 or 20 (north or south I guess given it spans the Equator) but I just wanted to know if anyone had any better suggestions.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm going to play around with a few of these suggestions and see what we get.  Does anyone know where we can find a map of suitable Transformations?  ESRI suggests WGS84 to SAD69 1 but there are other options in the transformation list.  The first suggestion is not always the best in my experience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to decide what distortion properties would you like to control for.  That is to say, are you interested in preserving area, distance or shape?  There is a decision support tool for selecting projections that is quite user friendly and available for free from Oregon State University ([Map Projection Selection Tool](http://projectionwizard.org/)).  Note that you can select the distortion property and a specific area of interest.  The tool yields a recommended projection, a central meridian and [PROJ.4 code](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use some projections that are provided by ESRI, depending on whether distance or area is important for you. They look very similar:

ESRI:102032 South_America_Equidistant_Conic

```
+proj=eqdc +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs
```

[image]

ESRI:102033 South_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs
```

[image]

Both projections are included in newer GDAL and QGIS versions as EPSG:102032 and EPSG:102033

A third choice can be EPSG:2317 PSAD56 / ICN Regional using Lambert Conformal Conical:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=9 +lat_2=3 +lat_0=6 +lon_0=-66 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-288,175,-376,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```