# Projecting Geoseries Geopandas doesn't work

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, geoseries

I have on geoseries that I would like to project to equal area conic of lambret. However my code doesn't work.

What is wrong with it?

```
#piece of g_source {GeoSeries}: 
156     POINT (-40.44880502028832 -11.46367489031081)
316     POINT (-39.41085010955187 -14.377529459967)
597     POINT (-41.38150747600145 -12.50530265608625)
611     POINT (-40.83168841504723 -9.831649257327703)
655     POINT (-38.65003368469574 -10.58169711296605)
762     POINT (-41.65309648409965 -13.84055043883477)
803     POINT (-40.16682973721372 -13.8128259068363)
895     POINT (-40.32563763661891 -11.44304599350725)
955     POINT (-42.83093325758571 -14.58912682266423)
1044    POINT (-44.19089700267293 -10.92335966009432)
1090    POINT (-42.48081539796195 -13.53028686200761)
1098    POINT (-42.5018315288937 -11.14269666158528)
1110    POINT (-40.58867787879641 -10.05547817406703)
1112    POINT (-42.68838715258138 -14.65174718137191)
1185    POINT (-43.50920272535527 -11.5860204677622)
1254    POINT (-40.48677193204426 -12.40027031089884)
1285    POINT (-42.15471265231525 -13.8609924490699)
1310    POINT (-43.01429033526334 -13.23693183675715)
1327    POINT (-41.07969455240436 -12.57893027527855)
1354    POINT (-40.4935550707856 -12.79451069316572)
1358    POINT (-45.59765266096689 -12.17602089331463)
1365    POINT (-39.12818338990706 -16.31180811000418)
1417    POINT (-41.8006242904709 -14.3024884040351)
1459    POINT (-38.87533320706946 -12.27064395995037)
1480     POINT (-41.7334747357795 -11.27345848882953)
1521    POINT (-40.54234022136743 -13.49153493325051)
1522    POINT (-43.26469993111385 -11.71467214706978)
Name: source, dtype: object

crs_source = {'init': 'epsg: 4674'}
crs_target = {'init': 'epsg: 102033'}

g_source = gpd.GeoSeries(data['source'].map(shapely.wkt.loads))
g_source.crs = crs_source
g_source.to_crs(crs_target)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoPandas uses [pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) for the projections ([requirements](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/requirements.txt)) and pyproj does not know the crs EPSG:102033 (does not exist) nor the [ESRI:102033 South_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102033/) (look at [GIS SE: Projected coordinate system for South America](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111527/2581))

But you can use the [Proj4 string](https://epsg.io/102033) of the  ESRI:102033 projection

With pyproj

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
from shapely.wkt import loads
point = loads("POINT (-40.44880502028832 -11.46367489031081)")
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj  = Proj('+init=EPSG:4674')
outProj = Proj('+proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs')
print transform(inProj,outProj,point.x, point.y)
(2068758.2788049988, 2248230.944751877)
```

Therefore, with GeoPandas

```
import geopandas as gpd
g_source = gpd.GeoSeries(point)
crs_source = ('+init=EPSG:4674')
crs_target = ('+proj=aea +lat_1=-5 +lat_2=-42 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=-60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs')
g_source.crs = crs_source
g_source
0    POINT (-40.44880502028832 -11.46367489031081)
dtype: object
g_source.to_crs(crs_target)
0    POINT (2068758.278804999 2248230.944751877)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Your explanation is perfect. However I don't know why your suggestion haven't worked in my Geoseries. When I run the code it return me this error {RuntimeError}b'projection not named'.